# Finding the minimum and maximum values of a symbolic non-linear function in a specific interval using Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, scipy-optimize

I wanted to find the minimum and maximum values of a user-specific 1-dimensional non-linear function which is defined using sympy.

I have written the following code:

```
import sympy as smp
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

max_width_constraint = 1.4
min_width_constraint = 0.6
b_beam_prismatic = 112.0e-09

x = smp.symbols('x')
b1 = 1.4
b2 = 0.0387587871746277
b3 = 1.28980485524082
b4 = 21.4341387770796
zeta = b1 * (1 - b2 * (x)**b3)**b4 

ans = sp.optimize.fmin_tnc(smp.lambdify(x, zeta), np.array([0.0]), approx_grad=True, bounds=[(0, 1)])
```

My guess value is x = 0. However, I am not sure whether this code is working properly or not. And I am also not sure on how to extract actual minimum value of the function and its location in the interval. I also want to extract the maxima of the same function in the same interval but do not know which command to use. Kindly suggest modifications that are neceaary in this regard.

Comment: This is a strange approach. Why find a numeric minimum when you can use pure sympy to find a symbolic minimum?

Comment: @Reinderien I am a researcher performing my work in the shape optimisation of electrostatically actuated microbeams. Even though in my sample code, I have written a zeta function, I will change that function according to my requirements. In addition, values of b1-b4 are not fixed but will be chosen based on the optimisation strategy chosen. However, for that particular zeta and set of values of b1-b4, I need to get the numerical minima and maxima in an interval [0, 1]. Now these extreme values may or may not be obtained by slope = 0 approach. Hence, I am using approach shown in sample code.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure whether this code is working properly or not

"Properly" is a little loaded here. There are several methods that trade off flexibility, performance and accuracy.

> I will change that function according to my requirements.

If you change the `b` parameters to the function the following methods will hold true. If you change the *form* of the function then all bets are off and you cannot assume anything at all.

```py
import scipy.optimize
import sympy
from sympy import symbols


def full_assisted():
    print('Full assisted')
    x = sympy.Symbol(name='x', real=True, finite=True, negative=False)
    b1 = 1.4
    b2 = 0.0387587871746277
    b3 = 1.28980485524082
    b4 = 21.4341387770796
    zeta = b1*(1 - b2*x**b3)**b4
    fun_min = sympy.lambdify(x, zeta)
    fun_max = sympy.lambdify(x, -zeta)
    args = {
        'bounds': ((0, 1),),
        'approx_grad': True,
        'disp': 0,
    }
    (x_min,), *_ = scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc(func=fun_min, x0=(1,), **args)
    (x_max,), *_ = scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc(func=fun_max, x0=(0,), **args)
    print(f'min: x={x_min} ζ~{fun_min(x_min)}')
    print(f'max: x={x_max} ζ~{fun_min(x_max)}')
    print()


def semi_assisted():
    print('Semi assisted')
    x, b1, b2, b3, b4 = symbols(names=('x', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'), real=True, finite=True, negative=False)
    values = {
        b1:  1.4,
        b2:  0.0387587871746277,
        b3:  1.2898048552408200,
        b4: 21.4341387770796000,
    }
    ζ = b1*(1 - b2*x**b3)**b4
    print('ζ =', ζ)

    ddx = sympy.diff(ζ, x)
    print('dζ/dx =', ddx)

    # Only works if ddx is a simple polynomial
    # sympy.roots(ddx.subs(values))
    root_terms = [ddx.args[i] for i in (6, -1)]
    roots = [sympy.solve(sympy.Eq(term, 0), x) for term in root_terms]

    for root_term, (root,) in zip(root_terms, roots):
        print(f'Root: 0 = {root_term}')
        print(f'      x = {root}')
        print(f'        = {root.subs(values)}')

    '''
    For the roots to have an effect within the bounds,
    1 = b2**(-1/b3): b2=1, or b3=inf
    If that does not happen, ζ over the interval of [0, 1] is monotonic.
    The sign of dζ/dx = -b1*b2*b3*b4*x**(b3 - 1)*(-b2*x**b3 + 1)**(b4 - 1) determines which bound is
    the minimum and which is the maximum.
    '''
    def make_bounds():
        for x_val in (0, 1):
            with_x = ζ.subs({x: x_val})
            with_val = with_x.subs(values)
            yield with_val, with_x, x_val
    bounds = sorted(make_bounds())
    for name, (with_val, with_x, x_val) in zip(('min', 'max'), bounds):
        print(f'{name}: x={x_val}, ζ~{with_val} = {with_x}')
    print()


def unassisted():
    print('Unassisted')
    b1 = 1.4
    b2 = 0.0387587871746277
    b3 = 1.28980485524082
    b4 = 21.4341387770796
    def zeta(x):
        return b1*(1 - b2*x**b3)**b4
    print(f'min: x=1 ζ~{b1*(1 - b2)**b4} = b1*(1 - b2)**b4')
    print(f'max: x=0 ζ={b1} = b1')


full_assisted()
semi_assisted()
unassisted()
```

```
Full assisted
min: x=1.0 ζ~0.6000051038276032
max: x=0.0 ζ~1.4

Semi assisted
ζ = b1*(-b2*x**b3 + 1)**b4
dζ/dx = -b1*b2*b3*b4*x**b3*(-b2*x**b3 + 1)**b4/(x*(-b2*x**b3 + 1))
Root: 0 = x**b3
      x = 0**(1/b3)
        = 0
Root: 0 = (-b2*x**b3 + 1)**b4
      x = ((1 - 0**(1/b4))/b2)**(1/b3)
        = 12.4294595795413
min: x=1, ζ~0.600005103827603 = b1*(1 - b2)**b4
max: x=0, ζ~1.40000000000000 = b1*(-0**b3*b2 + 1)**b4

Unassisted
min: x=1 ζ~0.6000051038276032 = b1*(1 - b2)**b4
max: x=0 ζ=1.4 = b1
```